# No grafica la imagen con QPixmap()

Tags: python, pyqt6

Me encuentro desarrollando un pequeño proyecto en Python, como practica libre usando el framework de PyQt6, y quiero mostrar una imagen con la librería QPixmap usando un QLabel y esto lo ingreso en un Layout vertical, pero cuando corro el programa no me grafica la imagen y tampoco me da ningún error

```
def generate_reproductor_tab(self):
    main_V_box = QVBoxLayout()
    button_h_box = QHBoxLayout()
    buttons_cointainer = QWidget()
    
    ****song_image = QLabel()
    pixmap = QPixmap("PYQT6\Reproductor\images\song_image.png")
    song_image.setPixmap(pixmap)
    song_image.setScaledContents(True)****
    
    button_repeat = QPushButton("Repeat")
    button_before = QPushButton("Before")
    button_play = QPushButton("Play")
    button_next = QPushButton("next")
    button_random = QPushButton("Random")
    
    button_h_box.addWidget(button_repeat)
    button_h_box.addWidget(button_before)
    button_h_box.addWidget(button_play)
    button_h_box.addWidget(button_next)
    button_h_box.addWidget(button_random)
    
    buttons_cointainer.setLayout(button_h_box)
    main_V_box.addWidget(song_image)
    main_V_box.addWidget(buttons_cointainer)
    self.reproductor_cointainer.setLayout(main_V_box)
```

Comment: lo primero que haría es cambiar el  \  por  /  en la ruta del archivo.

Comment: Ya lo hice, tampoco funciona

Comment: Asegurate de que esa ruta relativa es correcta de acuerdo al directorio de trabajo de tu app, por defecto el directorio de tu script principal ejecutado. Por ejemplo, si tu script esta en `Reproductor` y no cambias el directorio de trabajo, la ruta seria `"./images/song_image.png"`

Comment: Gracias, eso resolvió el error. Los extraño es que ya habia utilizado el back slash en otras imagenes y me habia servido

Comment: @sebastianBerrio la barra invertida  se usa también  para denotar [secuencias o caracteres de escape](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caracteres_de_escape) (como `\n` (nueva línea) o `\t` (tabulación)). Esto puede causar problemas ya que por ejemplo, la `\t` de `"\Documentos\trabajos"`  denota una tabulación y la ruta sería incorrecta (`"\Documentos    rabajos"`). Hay formas de usar la barra invertida para las rutas, como escapar la propia barra, pero en mi opinión simplemente usa `/` como se usa en sistemas UNIX-like (aunque estés en Windows), es universal y te evita este tipo de problemas.